# Not able to add input box and text using JADE template

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug

I am trying to add `input checkbox` with `object.text` - using jade template. But I not able to add that. I am getting simply the text instead input element. how to solve this:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en", ng-app)
    head
        title hellow there
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/style.css')
    body
        h1 Jade - node template engine
        #container(ng-controller="todoController")
            span {{rest}}
            ul
                li(ng-repeat='todo in todos') input(type='checkbox') {{todo.text}}


script(src='js/lib/angular/angular.js')
script(src='js/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js')
script(src='js/app.js')
```

the output i am getting is:

```
input(type='checkbox') Good Morning //no input box displays
input(type='checkbox') Good after Noon //no input box displays
```

any one find me the wrong what i do here please?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: i declared there as `checkbox` - right?

Comment: any error you are getting of indentation?

Comment: No I am not get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It was not clear, but now i think you are tring to do something like this:

```
li(ng-repeat='todo in todos')
  input(type='checkbox', name="p", id="p")label(for="p")|pip
```

from http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/

[image]

Comment: Actually this is droped down from the list. the result has not come as expected.

Comment: if I add span, then it works fine. But I don't want to use that:
input(type='checkbox')span{{todo.text}}

Comment: I guess, I am missing some stuff, between element and text to be handlred properly.